PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Looking at sudo dmesg -w -T i can see the following errors periodically being reported.
[Sat Jul  6 15:01:10 2024] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: Correctable error message received from 0000:00:1d.0
[Sat Jul  6 15:01:10 2024] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[Sat Jul  6 15:01:10 2024] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0:   device [8086:7a34] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[Sat Jul  6 15:01:10 2024] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
[Sat Jul  6 15:05:33 2024] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: Correctable error message received from 0000:00:1d.0
[Sat Jul  6 15:05:33 2024] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[Sat Jul  6 15:05:33 2024] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0:   device [8086:7a34] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[Sat Jul  6 15:05:33 2024] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
^C

How do I determine where the problem is?
It looks like its possibly related to my NVMe SSD.
lspci -s 00:1d.0 -vv` :
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7a34 (rev 11) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])     
Subsystem: Razer USA Ltd. Device 3006   Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR-
FastB2B- DisINTx+   
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-    
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes   Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 126 
IOMMU group: 13     
Bus: primary=00, secondary=6e, subordinate=6e, sec-latency=0    I/O behind bridge: [disabled] [16-bit]  Memory behind bridge: 74200000-742fffff [size=1M] [32-bit]  
Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled] [64-bit]  
Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA- VGA- VGA16+ MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B- PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-    
Capabilities: <access denied    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

Results of lspci -s 6e:00.0 -vv :
6e:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller S4LV008[Pascal] (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller S4LV008[Pascal]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    IOMMU group: 25
    Region 0: Memory at 74200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme

